# "Error: Cross origin null forbidden" with JSDOM trying to get a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, api, jsdom

I'm trying to get the blocked countries for a youtube video by its ID using the API provided by unblockvideos.com as a json file, in a node.js environment. I'm using the same syntax to get youtube video metadata with the youtube API v3 and that is working just fine, so I don't know why this would deliver an error.

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);


$.get('https://api.unblockvideos.com/youtube_restrictions?id=vMHZdfRWF94', function(ubjson) {

  //code

});
```

here is my console output:

Error: Cross origin null forbidden
    at dispatchError (/home/nodeworkspace/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:60:19)
    at Object.validCORSHeaders (/home/nodeworkspace/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:72:5)
    at receiveResponse (/home/nodeworkspace/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:845:21)
    at Request.client.on.res (/home/nodeworkspace/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:677:38)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Request.onRequestResponse (/home/nodeworkspace/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/request/request.js:1066:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:544:21) undefined

Answer (score -3):

You're running into a CORS issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Likely, the API is refusing to serve content to your browser because the 'domain' of your browser isn't accepted by unblockvideos.com.

You'd have to contact unblockvideos.com to have them whitelist your domain.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. That's interesting, because it works on my Chrome browser and using wget on the same machine also works, so I understand that the issue is that the simulated browser of the script is reporting a different 'domain' to the API than the other one?

Comment: I would expect wget to not fail, but I would of expected Chrome to throw the CORS error unless the domain is accepted.  

Since it is failing in JSDOM (as noted in your stack trace), I then suspect the issue might be with having an origin of "null".  It IS possible it is an issue with JSDOM itself... 

I found this list:  https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2024

Sorry, I can't dig into their tests to determine if it fits your use-case.  But you could try to ensure your JSDOM is on the latest release and see if you still get the error...  Good luck

Comment: Updating JSDOM didn't do anything for me, but I solved the issue by using https.get instead to get the file. Thanks for the support :)